# How can I forward a MMS in Google Voice?

Tags: google-voice

I have received a MMS in Google Voice. How can I forward it to another phone number or email address?

Example of MMS in Google Voice:

[image]

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate, Chrome. I tried Googling the question and couldn't find any official help articles on it.

> Have you considered taking a screenshot of the MMS and sending it in a new message?

No because it'll decrease the resolution of images.

> Have you considered copying the contents of the MMS and pasting it into a new message?

There is no convenient way to copy the contents of the MMS.

Comment: This makes no sense to close the question as a duplicate of a question removed by  Roomba.

Comment: This shouldn't be closed.

Comment: Voting to reopen as the linked question is deleted.